# Create Flask views that render different templates without repeating code

Tags: python, flask

I want to define multiple endpoints that render different templates, without writing out each one. The endpoints are all similar, one looks like:

```
    @app.route('/dashboard/')
    def dashboard():
        return render_template('endpoints/dashboard.html')
```

I tried defining a function in a for loop for each endpoint name, but the problem is that the name of the function stays the same and Flask raises an error about that.

```
routes = ['dashboard', 'messages', 'profile', 'misc']

for route in routes:
    @app.route('/' + route + '/')
    def route():
        return render_template('endpoints/' + route + '.html')
```

How can I create these views without repeating myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do this. Instead, use a variable in the route to capture the template name, try to render the template, and return a 404 error if the template doesn't exist.

```
from flask import render_template, abort
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

@app.route('/<page>/')
def render_page(page):
    try:
        return render_template('endpoints/{}.html'.format(page))
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
```

---

Alternatively, and less preferably, you can use the same function name as long as you provide Flask with unique *endpoint* names. The default name is the name of the function, which is why Flask complains.

```
for name in routes:
    @app.route('/', endpoint=name)
    def page():
        return render_template('endpoints/{}.html'.format(name))
```